# FreeMarker : two list show in one table

Tags: freemarker

My question like this:

I have two list  :

> list ups = {up1,up2}  list downs = {down1 , down2 , down3}

I need a table like this :

```
      ups                        downs
  no        name           no             name    
 ${up1.no}  ${up1.name}  ${down1.no}    ${down1.name}
 ${up2.no}  ${up2.name}  ${down2.no}    ${down2.name}
                         ${down3.no}    ${down3.name}
```

My code is given below:

```
    <#list downs as down>
     <tr>
     <td>ups?</td>
     <td>${down.no}</td>
     <td>${down.name}</td>

     </tr>
     </#list>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that the size of the two lists can differ. That complicates things a bit, but like this:

```
<#assign maxSize = (downs?size < ups?size)?then(ups?size, downs?size)>
<#list 0 ..< maxSize as i>
  <td>${(ups[i].no)!}</td>
  <td>${(ups[i].name)!}</td>
  <td>${(downs[i].no)!}</td>
  <td>${(downs[i].name)!}</td>
</#list>
```

The `(...)!` thing is needed to suppress the error when there's no more more item in one list, but there still is in the other.

(The `maxSize` calculation won't be needed in 2.3.28 where you can just write `0 ..< [ups?size, downs?size]?max` in 2.3.28.)